# @Autowired annotation in spring "Manager" classes

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a problem with @Autowired annotation in spring.
I have a RestController class:

```
 package sptool.controller;

    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryManager categoryManager;

  //Methods
}
```

CategoryManager interface:

```
package sptool.managers;
public interface CategoryManager {
    public void save(Category category);
    public Category getCategoryById(int id);
    public List<Category> getAllCategories();
    public void updateCategory(Category category);
    public void deleteCategory(int id);
}
```

CategoryManagerImpl class:

```
package sptool.managers;
@Service
public class CategoryManagerImpl implements CategoryManager {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;
   //Methods
}
```

Every time compile code I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sptool.managers.CategoryManager sptool.controller.CategoryController.categoryManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sptool.managers.CategoryManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Bun when I create ApplicationContext and try to get categoryManagerImpl bean there are no problems:

```
applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigurationClass.class);
application.getBean("controllerManagerImpl"); //<< works
```

Does anybody knows where could be a problem?

Thanks.

**Added**

Configuration class:

```
package sptool.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"sptool.managers", "sptool.dao", "sptool.controller", "sptool.model"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("annotated.packages"));
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( new String[] {"sprool.model"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jooq.sql-dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("show.sql"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_factory", env.getProperty("current.session.class"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sptool.managers.CategoryManager sptool.controller.CategoryController.categoryManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sptool.managers.CategoryManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at sptool.controller.App.main(App.java:18) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sptool.managers.CategoryManager sptool.controller.CategoryController.categoryManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sptool.managers.CategoryManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sptool.managers.CategoryManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: did you use more than one impl class for 'CategoryManager'?

Comment: No, I have only one class(CategoryManagerImpl) which implements CategoryManager interface.

Comment: There is no annotation `@SpringBean` in current Spring versions. If this annotation is from another library, please include some links.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below changes:

```
@Service
public interface CategoryManager {
    public void save(Category category);
    public Category getCategoryById(int id);
    public List<Category> getAllCategories();
    public void updateCategory(Category category);
    public void deleteCategory(int id);
}
@Component
public class CategoryManagerImpl implements CategoryManager {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;
   //Methods
}
```

The problem you are facing is because spring is not able to recognise the bean CategoryManager as it is not annotated with Service/Component. Doing the above should solve this problem.

Just FYI, if you have more than one implementations for CategoryManager I would recommend you to include an identifier for the implementation by using @Component(value="myComponent")

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I've changed CategoryManagerImpl to:

@Component(value = "categoryManager")
public class CategoryManagerImpl implements CategoryManager {...}

and CategoryManager to:
@Service
public interface CategoryManager {...}

But it didn't help.

Comment: can you tell me what your config looks like? Are you using auto configuration?

Comment: Also, please share the entire call stack

Comment: CategoryManagerImpl belongs to which package is that package scanned? Also, since you are using annotations, I would recommend you to comment out the @@ComponentScan annotation and try once. For your repositories you can use @@EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: I've added packages to classes. When I've commented out @CompopentScan annotation nothing changed.

Comment: can you come on chat?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for chat.

Comment: The configuration and pattern I have suggested works for me. There must something else going wrong in your app. Remember that you remove the ComponentScan annotation, keep the Service annotation on CategoryManager and Component annotation on CategoryManagerImpl. These things are a must. If after doing this also it isnt working, feel free to email me at kumar.badgujar@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Since this *`CategoryManagerImpl`* is annotated with *`@Service`*, you don't need to declare it again in the spring servlet (as *`< bean class="..CategoryManagerImpl " >`*), remove this in your spring servlet otherwise it can't be qualified which bean to inject to *`CategoryManager`* 
and after removing it, you will also need to remove :

```
applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigurationClass.class);
application.getBean("controllerManagerImpl"); //<< works
```

And finally this *CategoryManager* will be injected by *CategoryManagerImpl* just fine.